# Flask unittest api url with variable

Tags: python, api, flask, python-unittest

I'm testing an API, and is:

```
@app.route("/my-api/<token>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def get_url(token):
    s = TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer("KEY")
    try:
        url = s.loads(token)
    except:
        abort(400, "URL not identified")

    head, tail = ntpath.split(url)
    head = head + "/"
    filename = ntpath.basename(url)

    return send_from_directory(directory=head, filename=filename), 201
```

and unittests like so:

```
class BasicTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.test_token1 = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsImlhdCI6MTYxNTA1NTA4NSwiZXhwIjoxNjE1MDc1MDg1fQ.InRlc3Qi.Nm37UI69YrvPdcKyr0iAOKY_m1AmqknydosWaJcuULxfxJcrVxTsXQor60nZjH0EBb3zWemD8LMKM1rzIdxf9B"
        self.test_token2 = "abc123"

    def test_get_url_201(self):
        with app.test_client() as client:
            response = client.get(
                f"/my-api/{self.test_token1}"
            )

        print(f"RESPONSE: {response}")

        assert response.status_code == 201

    def test_get_url_400(self):
        with app.test_client() as client:
            response = client.get(
                f"/my-api/{self.test_token2}"
            )

        assert response.status_code == 400

def test_201(self):
    with unittest.mock.patch("flask.send_from_directory") as mocked:
        mocked.return_value = "Test Mock"
        response = app.test_client().get(f"/my-api/{self.test_token1}")
        print(response)

    self.assertTrue(mocked.called)
    assert response.status_code == 201
```

I'm trying to get the api to return a status_code of 201, but instead I get 404. Where am I going wrong?

EDIT: the first two tests are integration tests. The unittest `test_201` was added. Both asserts fail: <Response streamed [400 BAD REQUEST]>

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is not unit test but api/integration test. That means you intentionally avoid mocking dependencies such as ntpath and send_from_directory.

That said, the fact that you get 404 (and not 400) implies that loads function is not throwing exception, which leaves us with 2 potential failure points: either head/filename are faulted or send_from_directory fails due to some arbitrary reason.

Start by printing head and filename to see if they are faulted. If both are valid, you will have to explore for what can cause send_from_directory to fail.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the original post to reflect your comments.